# Problems in passing parameters to custom middleware

Tags: reactjs, redux

Hi I am passing an id to the custom middleware I created in redux. here is my Dispatch function:

```
/** NPM Packages */
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import fetchCategory from "../../../actions/categoryAction";
import deleteCategory from "../../../actions/categoryDeleteAction";

/** Custom Packages */
import List from "../List";
//import API from "../../utils/api";

class Category extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { categories: [], mesg: "", mesgType: "" };
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
  }

  /** Hook Call */
  componentDidMount = async () => {
    if (this.props.location.state)
      this.setState({
        mesg: this.props.location.state.mesg,
        mesgType: this.props.location.state.mesgType
      });

    this.closeMesg();
    this.props.fetchCategory();
  };

  /** Methods */
  onChange = e => this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  onDelete = id => {
    /*await API.delete("categories/" + id)
      .then(res => {
        const categories = this.state.categories.filter(el => el._id !== id);
        this.setState({
          categories: categories,
          mesg: res.data.msg,
          mesgType: "success"
        });

      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
      this.closeMesg();*/
      this.props.deleteCategory(id);
  };

  closeMesg = () =>
    setTimeout(
      function() {
        this.setState({ mesg: "", mesgType: "" });
      }.bind(this),
      30000
    );

  /** Rendering the Template */
  render() {
    const { mesg, mesgType } = this.state;
    return (
      <>
        {mesg ? (
          <div
            className={"alert alert-" + mesgType + " text-white mb-3"}
            role="alert"
          >
            {mesg}
          </div>
        ) : (
          ""
        )}
        <List
          listData={this.props.categories}
          listName="category"
          _handleDelete={this.onDelete.bind(this)}
        />
      </>
    );
  }
}

const matchStatestoProps = state => {
  return { categories: state.categories };
};

const dispatchStatestoProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    fetchCategory: () => dispatch(fetchCategory),
    deleteCategory: (id) =>dispatch(deleteCategory(id))
  };
};

export default connect(matchStatestoProps,dispatchStatestoProps)(Category);
```

Here is action:

import API from "../pages/utils/api";

```
const deleteCategory = (id,dispatch) =>{
    API.delete("categories/" + id)
      .then(() => {
        dispatch({type:'DELETE'})
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
}

export default deleteCategory;
```

here is my reducer:

```
const initState = [];

const categoryReducer = (state = initState, { type, payload }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case "FETCH_CATEGORY":
      return payload.data;
    case "DELETE":
      alert("Data Deleted");
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default categoryReducer;
```

Now i am getting this error :

```
Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.
▶ 6 stack frames were collapsed.
deleteCategory
src/app/pages/isolated/category/Categories.js:92
  89 | const dispatchStatestoProps = dispatch => {
  90 |   return {
  91 |     fetchCategory: () => dispatch(fetchCategory),
> 92 |     deleteCategory: (id) =>dispatch(deleteCategory(id))
  93 |   };
  94 | };
  95 |
```

If possible could someone say where am I going wrong?

Or is there any other way to pass parameters to the custom middleware?

Comment: are you using redux thunk ???

Comment: yes I am using redux thunk

Comment: add your Categories.js code i'll correct you

Comment: Done added the code

Answer (score 0):

You can refer my [react project](https://github.com/karenaprakash/final-project.git)

```
class Category extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { categories: [], mesg: "", mesgType: "" };
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
  }

  /** Hook Call */
  componentDidMount = async () => {
    if (this.props.location.state)
      this.setState({
        mesg: this.props.location.state.mesg,
        mesgType: this.props.location.state.mesgType
      });

    this.closeMesg();

    this.props.dispatch(fetchCategory());  // we have to dispatch our action like 

  };

  /** Methods */
  onChange = e => this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

  onDelete = id => {
      this.props.dispatch(deleteCategory(id));
  };

  closeMesg = () =>
    setTimeout(
      function() {
        this.setState({ mesg: "", mesgType: "" });
      }.bind(this),
      30000
    );

  /** Rendering the Template */
  render() {
    const { mesg, mesgType } = this.state;
    return (
      <>
        {mesg ? (
          <div
            className={"alert alert-" + mesgType + " text-white mb-3"}
            role="alert"
          >
            {mesg}
          </div>
        ) : (
          ""
        )}
        <List
          listData={this.props.categories}
          listName="category"
          _handleDelete={this.onDelete.bind(this)}
        />
      </>
    );
  }
}

const matchStatestoProps = state => {
  return { categories: state.categories };
};

export default connect(matchStatestoProps)(Category);
```

In your deleteCategory : you can access dispatch like

```
const deleteCategory = (id) => async (dispatch) =>{
   await API.delete("categories/" + id)
      .then(() => {
        dispatch({type:'DELETE'})
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
}

export default deleteCategory;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use redux-thunk as a middleware to handle async operations in Actions. Actions must be return plain objects, which means, something like below,

```
{
  type : "DELETE",
  payload : data
}
```

But in the Delete action you return a Promise, so that's why it is saying Actions must be return only plain objects. To handle this situation you can use a middleware like reduxt-thunk. 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-thunk

Edit - 
If you use the Redux-thunk, In the `catch` bloack of the `deleteCategory`, you didn't return any object. You just `console.log()` the error. return the err from catch block and see if you see any errors with your `API` call